# Set class of DIV in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have next HTML code:

```
<div class="small-3 column cell" 
     ng-repeat="cell in line track by $index">

     {{ cell }}

</div>
```

How can I add additional class for DIV element based on {{ cell }} value.  For example, 'empty' for cell=0, and 'full' for cell != 0 ?

Comment: See [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass).

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="..." ng-repeat="cell in line" ng-class="{empty:(cell==0), full:(cell!=0)}">
    ...
</div>
```

which can be further reduced to

```
<div class="..." ng-repeat="cell in line" ng-class="(cell==0) ? 'empty' : 'full'">
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use anything the [angular expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) supports. [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) will be best for what you describe.

If the logic you require is more complicated than what you can do with ng-class you can always create a controller for this scenario.

```
<div class="small-3 column cell" ng-controller="MyCtrl"
     ng-repeat="cell in line track by $index">

     <div class="{{getClass()}}"></div>

</div>

function MyCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.getClass = function() {
      if($cell == whatever) return "whatever";
      return "nothing";
   }
}
```